# Query format with f-string

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.6, f-string

I have very big dictionary that I want to insert into MySQL table. The dictionary keys are the column names in the table. I'm constructing my query like this as of now:

```
bigd = {'k1':'v1', 'k2':10}
cols = str(bigd.keys()).strip('[]')
vals = str(bigd.values()).strip('[]')
query = "INSERT INTO table ({}) values ({})".format(cols,vals)
print query
```

Output:

```
"INSERT INTO table ('k2', 'k1') values (10, 'v1')"
```

And this works in Python2.7

But in Python 3.6 if I use string literals like this:

```
query = f"INSERT INTO table ({cols}) values ({vals})"
print(query)
```

It prints this:

```
"INSERT INTO table (dict_keys(['k1', 'k2'])) values (dict_values(['v1', 10]))"
```

Any tips?

Comment: You shouldn't be forming query strings with string formatting **at all**, it exposes you to injection attacks. Read the docs for the database engine you're using, which tell you how to do it by putting placeholders in your query and letting *them* do the formatting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the tip. Will switch to placeholders. But is there a way to get rid of those "dict_keys" for some other similar application, which will maintain quotes around string and no quotes around ints.

Comment: The problem was you were doing it a naive way to start with, mangling strings of list literals. `','.join(map(repr, whatever))` is neater and continues to work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yup that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your curiosity, you should realize that you've cast these to `str`, getting the representation of `dict_keys/values` to be inserted into the `f-string`.

You could just cast to tuples and then insert:

```
cols = tuple(bigd.keys())
vals = tuple(bigd.values())
q = f"INSERT INTO table {cols} values {vals}"
```

but, as the comment notes, this *isn't* a safe approach.

Comment: I tried this ` INSERT INTO user ('id', 'field2') values ('1', 'value2') ` - there is single quotes surrounding field names, and it throws the syntax error. `  syntax error at or near "'id'"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO user ('id', `.

Comment: btw, its a cool construct :)